# Appending a list of movies MP4s causes the sound to be dropped or garbled at some point

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, ffprobe

**Update** I am able to reproduce the issue by concatenating 10 Hello.mp4 clips and see the audio drop out/garbled at about 5 seconds playback. This is via VLC latest 3.0.8 on Windows7 64bit.  Window Player zero sound.  Media Player Classic it plays fine all 10 audio or the word "Hello". The same movie when dragged onto Whatsapp the PC app plays OK but no sound if played from the Phone Whatsapp.  Perhaps its my computer too slow in the production of this clip??? I don't know what to trust anymore.

I copied the same ffmpeg.exe onto my kid's Windows10 laptop and was able to produce the same behavior with sound dropping out with VLC however Windows10 media player is able to play the audio without a glitch.

You can reproduce the same on your end with this batch file

_HELLO_MP4s.CMD

```
rem 2:07 AM 2/8/2020
rem 
rem  
SET EXE="S:\_BINS\FFmpeg 4.2.1 20200112\bin\ffmpeg.exe"

SET ROOTPATH=.\

SET OUT_FILE="%ROOTPATH%HELLOs.MP4"

SET IN_FILES_LIST="%ROOTPATH%IN_FILES_LIST.TXT"
ECHO file '%ROOTPATH%HELLO.mp4' > %IN_FILES_LIST% 
ECHO file '%ROOTPATH%HELLO.mp4' >> %IN_FILES_LIST% 
ECHO file '%ROOTPATH%HELLO.mp4' >> %IN_FILES_LIST% 
ECHO file '%ROOTPATH%HELLO.mp4' >> %IN_FILES_LIST% 
ECHO file '%ROOTPATH%HELLO.mp4' >> %IN_FILES_LIST% 
ECHO file '%ROOTPATH%HELLO.mp4' >> %IN_FILES_LIST% 
ECHO file '%ROOTPATH%HELLO.mp4' >> %IN_FILES_LIST% 
ECHO file '%ROOTPATH%HELLO.mp4' >> %IN_FILES_LIST% 
ECHO file '%ROOTPATH%HELLO.mp4' >> %IN_FILES_LIST% 
ECHO file '%ROOTPATH%HELLO.mp4' >> %IN_FILES_LIST% 

SET OPTIONS= -f concat -safe 0 -i  %IN_FILES_LIST%  -c copy -y  %OUT_FILE%

SET INFO_FILE="INFO.TXT"

%EXE% %OPTIONS%  1> %INFO_FILE% 2>&1 

ECHO ======================== >> %INFO_FILE% 
ECHO OUT_FILE=%OUT_FILE%  >> %INFO_FILE% 
ECHO EXE=%EXE%  >> %INFO_FILE%
ECHO OPTIONS=%OPTIONS%  >> %INFO_FILE% 
ECHO ======================== >> %INFO_FILE%
```

**Original Post**
My process is in 3 steps
Step 1) Corresponding to each bitmap I have 00.JPG ... NN.JPG I combine a list of "SOURCE" mp3 audio into a single audio mp3 to produce matching 00.MP3 ... NN.MP3

I had glitch here where one my mp3 was not of the correct Sample Rate, however a kind soul in this forum helped me fix that.
You can read the details here:

[When I append a silent audio (mp3) to an existing list of audio it garbles the final audio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60089210/when-i-append-a-silent-audio-mp3-to-an-existing-list-of-audio-it-garbles-the-f)

Step 2) combine each mp3 from previous with a the filename matching bitmap to produce a movie .MP4

IOW,

- 00.JPG + 00.MP3 >> 00.MP4
- 01.JPG + 01.MP3 >> 01.MP4
- and so on

From this run of 24 subparts, I hand tested some of these movies against Whatsapp and they are accepted fine.
However, the final MOVIE.MP4 is **not**.
I will list below their info from ffprobe.

Step 3) combine the list of movies from previous into a final MOVIE.MP4
This is where I have been having random issues typically with audio, currently this audio drops at about 20s from start. Corresponding to roughly movies parts 04.mp4 to 07.mp4

I play the videos via VLC but Windows Media Player has even worse playback.

I am able to reproduce Step3 and thus MOVIE.MP4 with following batch file

```
rem 10:33 PM 2/6/2020
SET EXE="S:\_BINS\FFmpeg 4.2.1 20200112\bin\ffmpeg.exe"

SET ROOTPATH=.\

SET OUT_FILE="%ROOTPATH%MOVIE.MP4"

SET IN_FILES_LIST="%ROOTPATH%IN_FILES_LIST.TXT"

SET OPTIONS= -f concat -safe 0 -i  %IN_FILES_LIST%  -c copy -y  %OUT_FILE%

SET INFO_FILE="INFO.TXT"

%EXE% %OPTIONS%  1> %INFO_FILE% 2>&1 

rem PAUSE
```

The content of IN_FILES_LIST.TXT

```
file '00.mp4'
file '01.mp4'
file '02.mp4'
...
file '23.mp4'
file '24.mp4'
```

(Step 2) uses the following :)
[image]

The following is ffprobe on the source audio MP3s  (Step 1)

```
MP3s_ORIGINAL.TXT
========================BEGIN 
[mp3 @ 0000000000513100] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from '.\PLAY\00.mp3':
  Duration: 00:00:03.36, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
[mp3 @ 00000000003f3180] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from '.\PLAY\01.mp3':
  Duration: 00:00:00.46, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
[mp3 @ 00000000004a3180] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from '.\PLAY\02.mp3':
  Duration: 00:00:00.58, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
[mp3 @ 0000000000623180] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from '.\PLAY\03.mp3':
  Duration: 00:00:00.84, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
[mp3 @ 00000000003a3180] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from '.\PLAY\04.mp3':
  Duration: 00:00:00.86, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
[mp3 @ 0000000000433180] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from '.\PLAY\05.mp3':
  Duration: 00:00:00.98, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
[mp3 @ 0000000000683180] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from '.\PLAY\06.mp3':
  Duration: 00:00:00.98, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
[mp3 @ 00000000004d3180] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from '.\PLAY\07.mp3':
  Duration: 00:00:00.98, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
[mp3 @ 00000000004c3180] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from '.\PLAY\08.mp3':
  Duration: 00:00:00.98, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
[mp3 @ 0000000000573180] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from '.\PLAY\09.mp3':
  Duration: 00:00:00.98, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
[mp3 @ 0000000000583180] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from '.\PLAY\10.mp3':
  Duration: 00:00:00.98, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
[mp3 @ 00000000005e3180] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from '.\PLAY\11.mp3':
  Duration: 00:00:00.98, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
[mp3 @ 0000000000553180] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from '.\PLAY\12.mp3':
  Duration: 00:00:00.98, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
[mp3 @ 0000000000563180] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate


trimmed because SO limits post to 30000 chars
```

The following is ffprobe on the MP3s concatenated with 2second Silence. All their Sample Rate 24K and Bit Rate 32k seems OK?? (Also Step 1)

```
MP3s_withSilenceAppended.TXT
========================BEGIN 
Input #0, mp3, from '00.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:05.42, start: 0.046042, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
Input #0, mp3, from '01.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:02.52, start: 0.046042, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
Input #0, mp3, from '02.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:02.64, start: 0.046042, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
Input #0, mp3, from '03.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:02.90, start: 0.046042, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
Input #0, mp3, from '04.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:02.93, start: 0.046042, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
Input #0, mp3, from '05.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.05, start: 0.046042, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
Input #0, mp3, from '06.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.05, start: 0.046042, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
Input #0, mp3, from '07.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.05, start: 0.046042, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
Input #0, mp3, from '08.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.05, start: 0.046042, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
Input #0, mp3, from '09.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.05, start: 0.046042, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
Input #0, mp3, from '10.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.05, start: 0.046042, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
Input #0, mp3, from '11.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.05, start: 0.046042, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
Input #0, mp3, from '12.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.05, start: 0.046042, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
Input #0, mp3, from '13.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:05.81, start: 0.046042, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
Input #0, mp3, from '14.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:02.93, start: 0.046042, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
Input #0, mp3, from '15.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:02.66, start: 0.046042, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
Input #0, mp3, from '16.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:02.66, start: 0.046042, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
Input #0, mp3, from '17.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:02.66, start: 0.046042, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
Input #0, mp3, from '18.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:02.83, start: 0.046042, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
Input #0, mp3, from '19.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:06.50, start: 0.046042, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
Input #0, mp3, from '20.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.05, start: 0.046042, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
Input #0, mp3, from '21.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.05, start: 0.046042, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
Input #0, mp3, from '22.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.14, start: 0.046042, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
Input #0, mp3, from '23.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:06.12, start: 0.046042, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
Input #0, mp3, from '24.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.14, start: 0.046042, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
```

The following is ffmpeg info output during the production of final movie MOVIE.MP4
(Step 3)

```
========================BEGIN 
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\VID\00.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:05.54, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 174 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 137 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\VID\01.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:02.71, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 269 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 242 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\VID\02.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:02.71, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 285 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 245 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\VID\03.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 275 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 239 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\VID\04.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 286 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 250 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\VID\05.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.21, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 281 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 249 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\VID\06.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.21, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 281 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 249 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\VID\07.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.21, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 150 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 115 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\VID\08.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.21, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 201 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 166 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\VID\09.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.21, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 247 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 214 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\VID\10.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.21, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 247 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 214 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\VID\11.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.21, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 131 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 95 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\VID\12.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.21, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 194 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 159 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\VID\13.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:05.88, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 207 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 169 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\VID\14.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 335 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 300 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\VID\15.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:02.88, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 365 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 342 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\VID\16.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:02.88, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 384 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 362 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\VID\17.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:02.88, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 390 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 368 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\VID\18.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 386 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 363 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\VID\19.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:06.71, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 204 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 169 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\VID\20.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.21, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 194 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 159 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\VID\21.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.21, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 194 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 159 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\VID\22.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.21, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 208 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 169 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\VID\23.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:06.21, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 204 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 166 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\VID\24.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.21, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 173 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 134 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\VID\MOVIE.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:01:29.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 239 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 203 kb/s, 23.53 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 30 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

I have not been able yet to reproduce the issue with a smaller set of movies, in the meantime if you would to get a copy I would have to upload an archive to a link so you can have them on your side.

Alternatively, if you would like me to provide additional info from these steps let me know what commands and I will be happy to provide.

Thank you.

Comment: Try using AAC instead of MP3. Some players don't like MP3 in MP4 and AAC is more widely and better supported.

Comment: @llogan how do I convert encoding from mp3 (which I may obtain from different sources) to ACC encoding?  Sorry if I am not using the correct terms encoding/packaging vs. file extension..

ffmpeg command line options options much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Use `-c:a aac`. See [FFmpeg Wiki: AAC](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC).

Comment: @llogan when I use -c:a aac instead of -c:a copy I get this huge tail silence in the produced movie both when played in VLC or visualized in Adobe Premiere, I have posted details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75828734/getting-a-lot-of-tail-silence-when-combining-an-image-and-audio-into-mp4-movie